# Python - Mean Length Function for All Files in Folder

Tags: python, text, directory, traversal

I have a function that finds the mean string length. Now I'm trying to write a function that will traverse and touch every txt file in the directory and return the file with the highest mean. What I've got right now doesn't seem to traverse properly. Pleeease help. Thanks.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os

def mean_length(file path):
    length = 0.0
    line_num = 0
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                length += len(line.strip())
                line_num += 1
    return length/line_num

def highest_mean():
    max_mean = 0 
    max_name = ""
    filepath = open("Desktop/Textfiles/moby.txt")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Desktop/Textfiles"):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.txt'):
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                if mean_length(filepath) > max_mean:
                    max_name = filename
                    max_mean = mean_length(filepath)
            return max_name
```

Comment: You seem to have an extra `for file in files` loop, the one after the `if file.endswith('.txt')` seems spurious.

Comment: why are you looping again through all files after the if in highest_mean function?

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. However, the function still won't work even without the extra for-loop. Is there anything else you see wrong?

Comment: You realize this only operates on the file *names* and not the contents, right?

Comment: You are returning immediately on finding any file greater than mean, not the max. And you probably need to send in a sequence with a single file, e.g. `mean_length([file])` if you want to be comparing the same things, `mean_length(file)` will always return 1

Comment: Yeah, that's my main problem. I can't figure out how to apply the mean_length function to the contents of each file in the directory. I should've been more clear.

Comment: `with open(string, 'r') as f:` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to go through all files to get the one with the highest mean, maybe with another two variables:

```
def mean_length(filepath):
    length = 0.0
    line_num = 0
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                length += len(line.strip())
                line_num += 1
    return length/line_num

def highest_mean():
    max_mean = 0 
    max_name = ""
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Desktop/Textfiles"):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.txt'):
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                m_length = mean_length(filepath)
                if m_length > max_mean:
                    max_name = filename
                    max_mean = m_length
   return max_name
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks better. Thanks. However it just returns ''. I think the problem is that the second function only finds the mean of the text file names, not the content inside. The statement -- with open(string, 'r') as f: -- was recommended already.

Comment: Your input to mean_length should not be a sequence of names, but a single filename/filepath

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you with this. I've edited my initial post (which I'll change back) to show the changes you've recommended. Basically I added -- filepath = open("Desktop/Textfiles/moby.txt") -- to the highest_mean function. Still isn't working.

Comment: It is not necessary to initialize filepath and open it outside the for loop, have you tried my solution, what did you get?

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple code do the same work of `len()` built in function.

```
var =input("enter your text to calculate here : ") 

def length(var):

    count =0
    for i in var:
        count +=1
    print(count)
lent(var)

print(len(var))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).